# How can I return a Flask redirect while wating for a request to complete?

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I have a Flask app with a view function that is set up like this (MWE):

```
from flask import redirect
import time, random

def quick_processing_function():
    return True

def long_processing_function():
    time.sleep(15)
    return random.rand() < 0.99

@app.route('target')
def function():
    result = quick_processing_function()
    if result:
        long_processing_function_that_may_fail()
        return redirect(SOME_EXTERNAL_SITE)
```

I'd like `long_processing_function_that_may_fail()` to not delay the service of the redirect to the external site, especially if it fails to complete. But it must run. Ideally, `long_processing_function_that_may_fail()` would run after the redirect is sent to the user. What's the best way to meet these requirements?

Comment: you might need to use a queue here, passing input parameters as body of the input to queue and then have a listener at the output of the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a separate thread

```
from flask import redirect
import threading
import time, random

def quick_processing_function():
    return True

def long_processing_function():
    time.sleep(15)
    return random.rand() < 0.99

@app.route('target')
def function():
    result = quick_processing_function()
    if result:
        x = threading.Thread(target=long_processing_function_that_may_fail, args=())
        x.start()
        return redirect(SOME_EXTERNAL_SITE)
```